Adding tuple rows to each subtuple group in sql
Client has one of the following tables:



row_index
id
seq
value_text




1007_0_0
1007
1
800


1007_0_0
1007
2
1110


1007_0_0
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_0
1007
5
100


1007_0_1
1007
1
800


1007_0_1
1007
2
1115


1007_0_1
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_1
1007
5
100


1007_0_2
1007
1
800


1007_0_2
1007
2
1105


1007_0_2
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_2
1007
5
100


1007_0_3
1007
1
800


1007_0_3
1007
2
1120


1007_0_3
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_3
1007
5
100


1007_0
1007
6
Rosedale


1007_0
1007
8
139



What I'm trying achieve is to have the tuple rows added to each subtuple(row_index) group for pivoting.
The final result should look like this:



row_index
id
seq
value_text




1007_0_0
1007
6
Rosedale


1007_0_0
1007
8
139


1007_0_0
1007
1
800


1007_0_0
1007
2
1110


1007_0_0
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_0
1007
5
100


1007_0_1
1007
6
Rosedale


1007_0_1
1007
8
139


1007_0_1
1007
1
800


1007_0_1
1007
2
1115


1007_0_1
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_1
1007
5
100


1007_0_2
1007
6
Rosedale


1007_0_2
1007
8
139


1007_0_2
1007
1
800


1007_0_2
1007
2
1105


1007_0_2
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_2
1007
5
100


1007_0_3
1007
6
Rosedale


1007_0_3
1007
8
139


1007_0_3
1007
1
800


1007_0_3
1007
2
1120


1007_0_3
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_3
1007
5
100




If the number of underscores tells you what's a tuple and what's a subtuple, you can delete..returning the tuples by targeting them with regexp_count(), join them to matching subtuples, then re-insert them after adding distinct subtuple suffixes, extracted with split_part().
Demo at db<>fiddle:
with tuple as (delete from your_table where regexp_count(row_index,'_')=1
                returning *)
insert into your_table
select distinct 
       tuple.row_index||'_'||split_part(subtuple.row_index,'_',3)
      ,tuple.id
      ,tuple.seq
      ,tuple.value_text 
from tuple join your_table subtuple 
  on  regexp_count(subtuple.row_index,'_')=2
  --and subtuple.row_index ~ ('^'||tuple.row_index)
  and tuple.id=subtuple.id
--returning *--this would suffice to show what got inserted
;
--full view to make the end result clearly match expectation
select * from your_table order by row_index,seq<6,seq;




row_index
id
seq
value_text




1007_0_0
1007
6
Rosedale


1007_0_0
1007
8
139


1007_0_0
1007
1
800


1007_0_0
1007
2
1110


1007_0_0
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_0
1007
5
100


1007_0_1
1007
6
Rosedale


1007_0_1
1007
8
139


1007_0_1
1007
1
800


1007_0_1
1007
2
1115


1007_0_1
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_1
1007
5
100


1007_0_2
1007
6
Rosedale


1007_0_2
1007
8
139


1007_0_2
1007
1
800


1007_0_2
1007
2
1105


1007_0_2
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_2
1007
5
100


1007_0_3
1007
6
Rosedale


1007_0_3
1007
8
139


1007_0_3
1007
1
800


1007_0_3
1007
2
1120


1007_0_3
1007
4
road, roadwork


1007_0_3
1007
5
100



It would be easier if you normalised your structure by replacing the row_index field with one integer identifier field and another one with a foreign key pointing at the parent tuple, in the same table. That way you can nest tuples however deep you want without having to parse/split/reassemble the text values in row_index, have faster lookups and joins thanks to the numeric type, and traverse the whole structure using pgrouting, Apache AGE, or just recursive CTEs.
The row_index can stay for backwards-compatibility, while you base your performance-sensitive operations on numeric identifiers. You could even let a trigger handle generating and maintaining row_index based on the foreign keys.

Thank you for the answer and recommendations. Although I can't modify the client's table, I was able to create a select statement from your solution.
